# How can I sign up for a Firefox account?

Tags: backup, browser, firefox-for-android, bookmarks, history

I want to back-up bookmarks and history, but the Sync "application" on my android device "cannot connect to network" and the webpage only provides a never ending swirl, even on a laptop.

(Yes, 'this is a question to ask at mozilla support'... which requires a Firefox account.)

Alternately, is there any browser that allows this manually, exported to some .txt or other file?

Edit: trying to install xBrowserSync, but it won't. I have a few versions, but each has this problem.

[image]

[image]

I scanned each at   VirusTotal first,  of  course.

Comment: Are you sure your Internet connections works at all? Have you tried to use a different Wifi, e.g. a public Wifi at a restaurant?

Comment: Yes. Certainly I'm doing other "interneting" to know if it's working. This question, for example.